# PBW basis for the quantized enveloping Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{g}_2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics, root-systems

I would like to know if you have any reference where I can find the canonical PBW basis for $U_q(\mathfrak{g}_2),$ computed using the action of the braid group as defined by Luzstig.

Alternatively I would like to know if I should expect Luztig's root vectors to be given by some sort of $q$-commutators or linear combinations of $q$-commutators.

Answer (score 6):

The canonical basis and the PBW basis are two different things. I don't expect a simple computation of the canonical basis (in G<sub>2</sub> the appropriate cluster algebra is not of finite type) while the PBW basis is not hard to compute for G<sub>2</sub> as there are only six positive roots.

Each of Lusztig's root vectors for the non-simple roots are scalar multiples of q-commutators of appropriately chosen other root vectors. This dates back to [Levendorskĭ-Soibelman](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-139/issue-1/Algebras-of-functions-on-compact-quantum-groups-Schubert-cells-and/cmp/1104203139.full) (Proposition 5.5.2), but the only place I know of where the scalar multiples are determined is in [my paper with Brundan and Kleshchev](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6900) (Theorem 4.2). The results mentioned in this paragraph are true in all finite types, not just G<sub>2</sub>.